Power Automate Error- Onedrive Access Denied. Alternative solution- recover local file and inport it in to new Account
Many people are encountering "Access Denied" errors when logging into Power Automate with their OneDrive account.  This can prevent login entirely, or you might be able to log in but your flows fail to run.enter image description here
After investigating this issue, it appears to be a problem with OneDrive's servers denying Power Automate access for some accounts (my Outlook account works fine, for example).
If you need your flows to work while waiting for customer support, here's a workaround:

Go to local file and get raw data: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power Automate Desktop\Console\Workspace. Each folder is your each flow store local in this folder. now go into 2 level you will something like this.
enter image description here
so you will need to open 3 file here. controlRepo.appmask - is your UI Elements, imageRepo.imgrepo - is your screenshoot saved , and script.robin is actual code flow itseft.

It's possible a more streamlined solution exists, but currently, my workaround involves transferring your files one at a time to your new flow. I my suggestion is flow import from imageRepo.imgrepo > controlRepo.appmask > script.robin



First create a flow to prep the copy string from the imageRepo.imgrepo and controlRepo.appmask

by copy this code here to you flow ( basic ctrl+C then ctrl+V to the Flow)
Clipboard.GetText Text=> ClipboardText
Text.Replace Text: ClipboardText TextToFind: $'''\\''' IsRegEx: False IgnoreCase: False ReplaceWith: $'''\\\\''' ActivateEscapeSequences: False Result=> ClipboardText
Text.Replace Text: ClipboardText TextToFind: $'''\"''' IsRegEx: False IgnoreCase: False ReplaceWith: $'''\\\"''' ActivateEscapeSequences: False Result=> ClipboardText
Text.SplitText.Split Text: ClipboardText StandardDelimiter: Text.StandardDelimiter.NewLine DelimiterTimes: 1 Result=> TextList
Text.JoinText.JoinWithCustomDelimiter List: TextList CustomDelimiter: $'''\\r\\n''' Result=> JoinedText


now open the imageRepo.imgrepo with notepad like image below then Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C
Then run the flow . here is will convert the clipboard to one single sting . now do the "Joinedtext" and copy it out and paste in the template below . now to the samething for controlRepo.appmask

Now you need  template put it in  a clipboard . Here is my Template:

Display.ShowMessageDialog.ShowMessage Title: $'''test''' Message: $'''test''' Icon: Display.Icon.None Buttons: Display.Buttons.OK DefaultButton: Display.DefaultButton.Button1 IsTopMost: False ButtonPressed=> ButtonPressed

# [ControlRepository][PowerAutomateDesktop]

{
  "ControlRepositorySymbols": [
    {
      "IgnoreImagesOnSerialization": false,
      "Repository": "[PASTE your controlRepo.appmask HERE]",
      "ImportMetadata": {
        "DisplayName": "Local computer",
        "ConnectionString": "",
        "Type": "Local",
        "DesktopType": "local"
      },
      "Name": "appmask"
    }
  ],
  "ImageRepositorySymbol": {
    "Repository": "[PASTE your imageRepo.imgrepo HERE]",
    "ImportMetadata": {},
    "Name": "imgrepo"
  },
  "ConnectionReferences": []
}


when you done now you can select all the ctrl+C then go to power automate create new flow and cotrl+V . now you will some UI element in and Image from the right side panel.  in here you can delect the Display message from main flow.

get the code into Main flow and sub flow.
now go Script.robin. if you dont have sub flow. then copy ( CTRL+C) everything under "@SENSITIVE: []"
if you do have subflow then stop before "FUNCTION [YOUR SUB FLOW NAME] GLOBAL"
now go back to Mainflow in power automate CTRL+V you will see the appear again.

if you have sub flow. create exactly same as the old name the go to Script.robin again . look for code between  "FUNCTION [YOUR SUB FLOW NAME] GLOBAL" and "END FUNCTION"  Ctrl+C then go back to power Automate. in the same sub flow name Ctrl+V. do the same for each each sub flow.
